# Output directory when building a WCF project in Visual Studio

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that is set to build in Debug x86. Visual Studio therefore sets the output path to \bin\x86\Debug, which seems logical enough.

The solution contains about 50 projects; the start-up project is a WCF project.

When I do a build, I would expect all output dlls to go to \bin\x86\Debug, as that is what is set in the project settings. But weirdly, I see dlls being created in bin\x86\Debug **and** in \bin. Why would Visual Studio put any dll in \bin if the output path is not set to that directory? It seems that all dlls go to \bin\x86\Debug, and all dlls **except for the start-up project** go into \bin. Any idea why it would do that? (We have other solutions that don't use WCF, and they don't have this problem.)

The other annoyance is if I run the service from Visual Studio and then try to access my service in a web browser, by going to http://localhost:1240/MyService.svc, it doesn't work, because the start-up project dll is missing from /bin. I therefore have to manually copy this one dll from \bin\x86\Debug to \bin, so that all dlls are found and the service runs normally. (We could of course add a custom post-build step that does the copy, but you'd think there'd be a better way!)

To those of you working on WCF projects, do you leave the output path at \bin\x86\Debug? (Perhaps there is a way to configure the service, eg in the web.config or .svc file, so that it knows the binaries are in \bin\x86\Debug instead of \bin?) Or do you change the output path to \bin so that you can run your service straight from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open the property page of you WCF Hosting project and goto tab Build, under the Output section of this tag there is a textbox that contains the location of the output binaries.

For a WCF project the binaries should go to bin directory irrespective of the build type (suc as Debug, Release). Make sure this value has been configured correctly.

The value needs to be configured for each build type\configuration.

Comment: Yes, that textbox is the "output path" I talk about in my post. So you're saying you just set this to bin, end of story. Seems strange though that if you change this output path, most files still go to bin anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: For non WCF project default output path points to bin\\[BuildConfiguration] folder. Since WCF service wants the dll's to be present in bin directory and not in any sub directory, the default project configuration for WCF project if created from Visual Studio is bin folder.

Comment: This bit me doing some MVC3 stuff, where binaries went into bin\x86\debug based on solution Configuration Manager settings. Hopefully this will help the next person flailing around.... Just change the site output to bin\

Comment: This is sad, i wan't to keep code and binaries separated, but MS just screws things up.

Answer (score -2):

If you need, for whatever reason, different outputs from different build configurations in different folders you could specify them like you did first and use a post build event command line that copies from your specified output folder to bin.
Like:

```
    - untested code -  
    COPY/Y "$(OutDir)\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\bin\"  
    - untested code -
```

Comment: Maybe you should test it before posting?