# Why do web service project not creating build or release folder inside bin

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-debugging

I have a wcf project here at work, when i try to compile it using debug it do create the files under bin folder not (bin/debug) and when i try to build the project using (bin/release) it again create the files at same location i.e bin.

Can anyone tell why it isn't creating debug/release folder?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/4678873/541432

Comment: Hmm. Seems like for WCF it will always go to bin directory. But I am still clueless about the fact why this is necessary? or why the debug/release folders are avoided

Comment: I do not think it's always. Go to Project Properties -> Build and under "Output" section, you can define the Output path depend on the configuration(Debug/Release)